# Как отключить в netbeans копирование при выделении?

Tags: ide, netbeans

Как отключить в netbeans копирование при выделении текста? Искал в опциях так и не нашел.

Comment: мне влом уже третий по счету раз регаться, если бы можно было использовать один аккаунт у вас везде - было бы очень удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю к нетбинсу это не относится, нет там такой опции. 
Посмотрите запущенные приложения, наверняка что-то подобное сидит у вас в автозагрузке. Например, у меня в Linux + KDE, этим занимается Klipper

Comment: но такое поведение буфера обмена наблюдается только в этой IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Может у вас какая-то сборка нетбинса, а не оф приложение? Я это к тому клоню, что, как сказал [@Павел Вершинин](/users/2927/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD), такого функционала в netbeans нет, а возможно делать с помощью макросов или сторонних плагинов.

Посмотрите на всякий случай Сервис -> Настройки -> Редактор -> Макросы

А так же проверьте список установленных плагинов.

Comment: >Может у вас какая-то сборка нетбинса, а не оф приложение?
Нет, официальный дистрибутив
>Посмотрите на всякий случай Сервис -> Настройки -> Редактор -> >Макросы
Проверил, чисто
>такого функционала в netbeans нет
нету, врошурстил все вкладки и перещелкал все чекбоксы... Сторонних плагинов не устанавливал. Изначально дистрибутив скачивал для C++, потом установил модуль поддержки PHP из каталога Netbeans и всё